# Unrequited permissions appeared for the app `Phone` and `Storage`

Tags: android

Below are the permissions appeared in my app manifest, those are `Location` and `SMS` only.

But after installing the app, it shows some other permission, which is `Phone` and `Storage` which I never mentioned a need of any of them anywhere in my app!

why these 2 appeared, and how to get rid of them, I do not need my user to misunderstood it, and think that I'm trying to access his private data!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

[image]

Comment: may its because of some library required that permission

Comment: Just open your manifest file and on the below left bottom there is a tab called Merged Manifest (currently it will be Text).By clicking 'Merged Manifest Tab' you can see the merged version of manifest, which will have all the features and permissions of all included libraries as well.